# Raspberry Pi can't send data to PC through serial communication

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, uart, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to send/receive data over the serial connection (GPIO UART pins) between a Raspberry Pi 2(raspian wheezy) and an STM32F4 board. I am using the sample code in the link: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart.

It works when I connect the TX and RX pins on the board together. However, when I connect RPI to my laptop by module USB-TTL PL2303 and use hyper terminal to see the result, the received characters are garbage characters. I don't understand why. Is there anything I missed? 
Could you give me some advice I could look for, please? Thank you!

Comment: Baud rate, stop bits, parity.............................

Comment: Have you set the correct baudrate/serial parameters in hyperterminal ? Usually it should be `115200-8-N-1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I use any baudrate? Or I have to baudrate of 115200?

Comment: You can use any baud rate that both ends support correctly.  Just set BOTH ENDS to the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using incorrect baud rate. It should be 115200 (115200-8-N-1) (you can use else but then you need to set both endpoints to the same baud). Check the baud rate of the serial connection using [stty](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty)

`stty -F /dev/ttyX`

or [setserial](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setserial). In case of baud rate error you can try what authors say:

> Try using a slower BAUD rate (or a single 0xFF byte which only has the
>   start bit low) and see if it works.  We had a problem using 115k2 baud
>   rate where our microcontroller communicating with the RPi could hit
>   113636baud or 119047baud.  113636baud had the lowest error margin so
>   we used it and TX from the RPi being received by the microcontroller
>   worked fine.  However when transmitting to the RPi nothing was ever
>   received. Changing the microcontroller to use 119047baud caused RX to
>   work.

Comment: tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B9600); 
cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; 
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
These are my configurations for serial communication. I set the baudrate of 9600 and I also use it for hyper terminal but it still receives garbage characters.

Comment: @uv_utna did you verify with minicom as tutorial suggests? Ensure Speed (baud rate): 115200
Bits: 8
Parity: None
Stop Bits: 1
Flow Control: None

Comment: My code was correct. there was a stupid mistake in the circuit. Thank you.